# Ember Data 1.13 findAll isn't working

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm just getting started with Ember 2.0 and I'm trying to build a simple CRUD application using Ember Data. I've been following the Ember guides online but I've run into an issue.

I'm populating default data into my store using `this.store.push` in my routes/application.js file. When I use `this.store.findRecord(modelName, id)` immediately after, it seems as though my data is persisting successfully:

[image]

However, when I use `this.store.findAll(modelName)`, I get a 404 as a result of an "Adapter operation failed" error:

[image]

I've done some searching around, but given such an ambiguous error I haven't had much luck. If anyone has any insight I'd greatly appreciate it! Here's the code I used to create the console output:

```
var wine = this.store.findRecord('wine', 5);
var wines = this.store.findAll('wine');
console.log(wine);
console.log(wines);
```

And an example of a model that I'm creating:

```
this.store.push('wine', {
  id: '5',
  name: 'Pink Moscato',
  vintage: '2014',
  description: 'The wine has aromas of Mandarin orange and sweet ' +
    'jasmine. It has subtle flavors of cherry, raspberry, and ' +
    'pomegranate.',
  imageUrl: 'https://placehold.it/290x290'
});
```

Comment: What does the errors array contain? What about backend logs? Adapter errors are typically HTTP errors (status error, CORS error, etc)

Comment: @elithrar It says "detail: Cannot GET /wines, status: 404, title: The backend responded with an error"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.store.findAll(modelName)` will fire HTTP request to your API backend. From what I've read it seems like you have no API server, and you only use `store.push` to mock data in Ember Data. So, I would recommend you to use:

`this.store.peekAll(modelName)` which will not fire any request and will give you local data.

> I find it odd that findRecord works, while findAll doesn't.

`findRecord` works for you while `findAll` doesn't because `findRecord` attemps to get local version of record, which is already present in your case (you use `store.push`) and tries to reload record in background to get latest data (you should see in your dev tools that even with `findRecord` request is fired to refresh it's data).

`findAll` is also cached, but it fires request first time when it is called.

[I recommend you to see my previous answer for more info and details of `peekAll` and `findAll`.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32359637/2166409)

> Also, what would be an example of an API server in this case?

Depends whether you want to use `RESTAdapter` or `JSONAPIAdapter`. In case of `RESTAdapter` your example response from API server (to `findAll('wine')`) could be:

```
{
    "wines": [
        {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Pink Moscato",
            "vintage": "2014",
            "description": "text",
            "imageUrl": "https://placehold.it/290x290"
        }
    ]
}
```

> I was under the impression that Ember Data could be used by itself.

Yeah, it could be used by itself, but you need to tweak your `Adapter`.

Comment: Ahh interesting, ```this.store.peekAll``` worked! I suppose I was assuming that Ember Data would be a substitute for an API backend

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on your answer some more? I find it odd that ```findRecord``` works, while ```findAll``` doesn't. Also, what would be an example of an API server in this case? I was under the impression that Ember Data could be used by itself. Thanks!